# WPf which one suits best a dataset or Entity Frame Work?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Normally as i know Entity frame work associated with WCF application , for standalone  desktop application  like  POS or Inventory application , is Entity Frame work suitable ? or WPF MVVM  Model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVVM is a design pattern that separates the UI from the implementation details.

The Entity Framework is (I believe) an ORM, designed to abstract application specific implementation details from the underlying storage.

Datasets offer little to no abstraction over the underlying storage.  I'd recommend using any ORM/DAL framework over directly interacting with datasets.

Both MVVM and the Entity Framework can be used in the same application because they offer abstractions at completely different layers.  When combined, the "model" in MVVM is the DAL/ORM layer.

Comment: Generic Datasets offer little to no abstraction over the underlying storage but **typed datasets** do. All you need is an xsd. Visual studio can generate an xsd from a database and it can generate a typed dataset from a xsd.

Comment: @K3b: All classes in EF are serialized by defult and you can save them as XML.

Comment: @k3b: Yes, that seems like it could be worth investigating.  I can't speak towards it because I've only used untyped datasets.

Answer (score 3):

To work with WPF; I’ll prefer to use Entity Frame work.

1-It will convert all tables to classes direct.

2-You can add partial class to tables to do some validation or extra variable

3-You don’t need to write to many procedures.

Of course it will be different from dataset, but with time you’ll never go back to dataset. I promise.

Answer (score 0):

Additional arguments

- Datasets work well when the database is disconnected. They can be saved and loaded as xml from a file or send over the wire to an other application. I am not shure wether this is possible with ef.
- As far as i know Datasets are not supported in silverlight apps or on windows-mobile7. They are supported in Dotnet-CompactFramework.